# Very very slow boot (over 1 minute) on Ubuntu after update to 16.10

Tags: boot, 16.10

I updated a few days ago from 16.04 to 16.10 and from that time I have a very very slow boot. My installation was Ubuntu Mate, now I use only gnome-shell desktop environment.

I ran`systemd-analyze plot` and the header of the html file as result is

```
Startup finished in 5.339s (firmware) + 4.470s (loader) + 10.464s (kernel) + 54.202s (userspace) = 1min 14.477s
```

Ubuntu 16.10 andrea-Lenovo-Z50-70 (Linux 4.8.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 09:15:00 UTC 2016) x86-64

The command `systemd-analyze blame` gives instead

```
     24.324s irqbalance.service
     18.427s preload.service
     17.988s dev-sda8.device
     14.710s keyboard-setup.service
     13.505s networking.service
     13.448s systemd-sysctl.service
     13.383s systemd-udevd.service
     11.562s accounts-daemon.service
     10.657s click-system-hooks.service
      9.196s mysql.service
      8.598s loadcpufreq.service
      8.554s ModemManager.service
      7.840s vboxdrv.service
      7.211s speech-dispatcher.service
      7.052s systemd-logind.service
      6.912s lm-sensors.service
      6.906s gpu-manager.service
      6.899s apport.service
      6.893s alsa-restore.service
      6.887s nvidia-persistenced.service
      6.875s thinkfan.service
      6.871s rsyslog.service
      6.859s avahi-daemon.service
      6.457s grub-common.service
      5.932s NetworkManager.service
      2.829s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1432\x2dA7AD.service
      2.188s colord.service
      2.182s media-Archivio.mount
      1.823s user@1000.service
      1.588s apparmor.service
      1.438s wpa_supplicant.service
      1.211s udisks2.service
      1.128s lightdm.service
      1.098s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      1.078s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.061s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.000s snapd.firstboot.service
       905ms upower.service
       807ms polkitd.service
       788ms binfmt-support.service
       708ms rtkit-daemon.service
       570ms dev-sda9.swap
       515ms packagekit.service
       448ms ntp.service
       383ms plymouth-start.service
       306ms systemd-resolved.service
       294ms pppd-dns.service
       251ms boot-efi.mount
       226ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       223ms dev-mqueue.mount
       216ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       204ms setvtrgb.service
       201ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       201ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       190ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       189ms dev-hugepages.mount
       178ms systemd-hostnamed.service
       165ms hddtemp.service
       156ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       150ms tlp.service
       149ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       146ms rc-local.service
       140ms systemd-journald.service
       135ms openvpn.service
       122ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       122ms dns-clean.service
       105ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
       104ms vboxweb-service.service
       103ms vboxautostart-service.service
       103ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       102ms console-setup.service
        80ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        53ms systemd-random-seed.service
        36ms clamav-daemon.socket
        36ms snapd.socket
        32ms plymouth-read-write.service
        12ms snapd.boot-ok.service
         9ms cpufrequtils.service
         8ms ureadahead-stop.service
         5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         2ms resolvconf.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

and the `critical-chain` is

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
```

The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

```
graphical.target @51.810s
└─multi-user.target @51.809s
  └─preload.service @33.381s +18.427s
    └─basic.target @26.477s
      └─sockets.target @26.477s
        └─snapd.socket @26.440s +36ms
          └─sysinit.target @26.376s
            └─apparmor.service @24.788s +1.588s
              └─local-fs.target @24.559s
                └─boot-efi.mount @24.307s +251ms
                  └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1432\x2dA7AD.service @21.427s +2.829s
                    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1432\x2dA7AD.device @21.413s
```

How can I have a normal boot time? Thank you